# How to use strings IDs like AFX_IDP_PARSE_REAL with my own string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

When I use DDX function in VC++6 and assign an Edit Control a variable of type double it displays a Message "Please Enter a number." when the string is not a number. I would like, though, to change this string to another string, because I am not using the English language for interface in my application.

I there any way (or at least, is there any standard way) to use these type of IDs with my own strings? I tried to put this ID in the string table of visual C++ 6 resource view, but it did not work.

I actually want to make the interface of the application with two languages.

Comment: Have you seen [How to modify the project settings and resource files to use localized MFC resources](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/198536)? Does it help? It's quite old, but then you are using VC6.

Comment: Thank you for your link. It works! I followed the instructions in the link and I could make AFX_IDP_PARSE_REAL display with another language.

Comment: Thank you for your link. It works! I followed the instructions in the link and I could make AFX_IDP_PARSE_REAL display with another language.

But the even when I change the project settings and resource files the MessageBox function and CFileDialog display dialogs with English Captions.

Is there any way I can use to modify the captions in MessageBox, CFileDialog, or any other common dialog?

Thanks!